# How can I create a pdf file with TCPDF, such that it doesn't ask to save the file after opening and closing the file?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I create a pdf file with PHP and TCPDF using the following code:

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetCreator('Mustermann');
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Max Mustermann');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Certificate');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->setHeaderFont([PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN]);
    $pdf->setFooterFont([PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA]);
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 15, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12, '', true);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
    $pdf->Output('certificate.pdf', 'I');
```

Here is the value of the `$html` variable I used:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr><td style="width: 33%;">
        <img src="/img/logo_en.png"     alt="" style="width: 120px;"/>
    </td><td style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
        <img src="/img/logo_university.png"          alt="" style="width: 120px;"/>
    </td><td style="width: 33%; text-align: right;">
        <img src="/img/logo_de.png" alt="" style="width: 120px;"/>
    </td></tr>
</table><br>


<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;">
    <div style="font-size: 2.2em; font-weight: normal;">
        CERTIFICATE
    </div><br>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
        Daniel Adams
    </div><br>
    <div>
        has successfully participated in
    </div><br>
    <div style="font-size: 1.8em; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;">
        COURSE FOR XYZ
    </div><br>
    <div>
        on May 6th, 2020 in Hamburg .<br><br>
        He is authorized to give courses in XYZ.
    </div>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 0.8em;">
    <img src="/img/signature.png" alt="" style="width: 280px;"/><br>
    Dr. med. August Tolezilek, PhD, MAS<br>
    Associate Professor in XYZ,<br>
    University of Berlin<br>
    Leader of XYZ International<br><br><br>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 0.7em; border-top: 1px solid black;">
    <br>
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Certificates International</span>, Main Street 1, D-12345 Berlin<br>
    kontakt@certificates.info &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="https://www.certificates.info">www.certificates.info</a>
</div>
```

which is a slightly modified example from the tcpdf website itself.

When I open the created pdf file under windows and close it again directly after opening, I get the messsage box "Do you want to save changes to the file before closing it?"

Why does that message appear? The created pdf file is supposed to be read-only.
I also have the problem with the generated pdf file, that scrolling is really slow, not like in other pdf file. What do I do wrong?

Comment: With which program are you opening this pdf ?

Comment: It is not reproduceable with the info you provided. I copied the code you gave, made sure `$html` does contain some valid html, and was not able to see your problem ([example_070.pdf](https://filebin.net/1d51gm2t3pyq2466/example_070.pdf?t=gk5di2vt))

Comment: I added the html I used to the question. Here is is [the file I get](https://filebin.net/iquyi5sv8chviam8/example01.pdf?t=xnml2inc) when generating

Comment: With which program are you opening this pdf ? ? (My browser does not complain when opening, and closing, the pdf )

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. With the browser I also don't get the message